# Randomly shuffle elements of one list and save the order of shuffling

Tags: python

I want to shuffle a list but store the order of the original list.
Something like this:

```
originallist=[1,2,3,4,5]
newlist=[]
orderlist=[]
for i in range(0,len(originallist)):
    randomindex=random.randrange(0,len(originallist))
    if randomindex not in orderlist:
        newlist.insert(randomindex,originallist[i])
        orderlist.append(randomindex)
    else:
        i-=1
```

The problem is that if `originallist` contains more than 2 variables, `orderlist` has one less element in it. and the missing element is random.
How do i fix this?

Comment: Python for loops don't work like that, `i -= 1` doesn't do anything useful. Also, the `randomindex` is likely to be out of bounds, so most elements are going to end up at the end of `newlist`, making `orderlist` not refer to the right index and `newlist` to be roughly the same order as `originallist`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a list of indices and shuffle the indices then lookup the original list in the order of the shuffled indices.

```
originallist=[1,2,3,4,5]
orderlist = list(range(len(originallist)))
random.shuffle(orderlist)
newlist = [originallist[i] for i in orderlist]

print (orderlist)
print (newlist)
```

Output:

```
[2, 0, 4, 1, 3]
[3, 1, 5, 2, 4]
```